# Correcting for multiple comparisons in interaction

Tags: interaction, multilevel-analysis, multiple-comparisons

I have 13 separate hierarchical linear regression models- all models have an interaction term (group by variable of interest) entered as the last step. Since I have 3 dummy coded groups, I have 2 p-values (i.e., a p-value for group A (reference group) vs B, and a p-value for group A (reference) vs C) for each of the 13 models. I want to correct for multiple comparisons, but am having trouble figuring out which p-values I need to correct for. For example, I do not think 0.05 / 26 would be correct as I am not making 26 comparisons (the interaction step is completed in one step). Any thoughts /recommendations other than bonferroni correction would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can cut your problem in half and improve your analysis by testing the overall significance of the "group by variable of interest" interaction in each model rather than focusing on the individual dummy-variable coefficients as you currently are. The p-values for the individual coefficients depend on your choice of reference value. If you happen to choose the reference level that is in the middle in terms of the magnitude of the interaction, you might have a significant and important difference between the two other groups that is lost due to "insignificant" p-values when they are individually compared against that reference.

A combined test could be a likelihood-ratio test of 2 models in each situation, one with and one without the interaction terms while all other predictors are included.

Second, the Bonferroni correction, despite (because of?) its simplicity is unnecessarily conservative. As the manual page for `p.adjust()` in R states:

> There seems no reason to use the unmodified Bonferroni correction because it is dominated by Holm's method, which is also valid under arbitrary assumptions.

Third, you might be hurting yourself with the multiple parallel models. If you apply your knowledge of the subject matter carefully, you might be able to build a single model that includes all of your predictors of substantive interest and avoid the inevitable loss of power when you try to correct for multiple comparisons among what seem to be otherwise highly similar models.

Comment: Put all the possible interaction terms into a single model and do a likelihood ratio "chunk" $\chi^2$ test of all interaction terms combined.  This provides a perfect multiplicity adjustment.